# Copying data from table1 to table2 based on 2 cells value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Table1 in worksheet A with base data:

| Town | Month | Sth | Sth | Sth | Sth | Sth | Sth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NY | June | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| NY | May | 1 | 13 | 4 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| LA | April | 5 | 43 | 67 | 5 | 5 | 765 |
| SF | December | 74 | 4 | 5 | 2 | 7 | 9 |

I have another Table2, in another worksheet, I have only Town and Month data but in many rows. I need to copy Sth columns if Town&Month.value is the same in both tables.

| Town | Month |
| --- | --- |
| NY | June |
| NY | May |
| LA | April |
| SF | December |
| NY | May |
| LA | April |
| SF | December |
| LA | April |
| NY | May |
| SF | December |
| NY | June |

Now, I use 2 for loops. 1st to loop each row in table2, and second inside 1st to loop each row in table1 and compare Town&Month.Value. If positive, then copy range. I was wondering if there is some more efficient way to do this, like create 2 arrays, one for each table and compare arrays or sth like that.

Below is my code

```
Sub kopiuj()
    Dim row As Long
    Dim copyRng As Range, pasteRng As Range
    
    row = 7
    If IsEmpty(Cells(row, 3)) Then
        MsgBox "No data"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(row, 3))
     If IsEmpty(Cells(row, 7)) And Cells(row, 6) = "xxx" Then
          MsgBox "No data"
           Exit Sub
     End If
     Set copyRng = szukaj2(Cells(row, 6).Value, Cells(row, 7).Value)
     If Not copyRng Is Nothing Then
        Set pasteRng = Range(Cells(row, 8), Cells(row, 25))
        copyRng.Copy pasteRng
     End If
     row = row + 1
    Loop
End Sub

Function szukaj2(ByVal przedplon As String, ByVal plon As String) As Range
  Dim PN As Worksheet
  Dim row As Integer
  Set PN = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("XXX")
  Dim rg As Range
    
  For row = 7 To PN.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).row Step 1

    If StrComp(przedplon, PN.Cells(row, 3).Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 And StrComp(plon, PN.Cells(row, 1).Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
     With PN
     Set rg = .Range(.Cells(row, 8), .Cells(row, 25))
     End With
     Set szukaj2 = rg
     Exit For
    End If
  Next
End Function
```

Comment: Looping arrays would be faster than looping ranges, yes.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)  Please provide details on the code you attempted, and explain on the specific issues you encountered.

Comment: @taller, that seems resonable. As there is a way to post code or quote error, how do I show the table? Updated question with my code.

Comment: Please edit your post to paste the code and data ( crate MD table with https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables ).

Answer (score 2):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac).

In Power Query, you could ***Join*** the two tables using `Month` and `Town` as the keys.

To use Power Query

- Create **Tables** from your data tables and name them, for example, `Table1` and `Table2` as you show.
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//Read in the two tables and set the data types
//Also create a List of the "Sth" Columns
    Source1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Sth Columns" = List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(Source1), each Text.StartsWith(_,"Sth")),
    Table1 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source1, {{"Town", type text}, {"Month", type text}} & List.Transform(#"Sth Columns", each {_, Int64.Type})),
    
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    Table2 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{{"Town", type text}, {"Month", type text}}),

//Join the tables
    Join = Table.NestedJoin(Table2,{"Town","Month"}, Table1, {"Town","Month"}, "Joined"),

//Expand the Sth columns
    #"Expand Sth" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Join, "Joined", #"Sth Columns")
    
in
    #"Expand Sth"
```

***Table1***
[image]

***Table2***
[image]

***Results***
[image]

*If you want the `Results` to be in some specific order, that can be done within the code.*

Answer (score 1):

- Loading tables into array and using `Dictionary` object to improve search efficiency (reduce looping times)

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrData1, arrData2, rngData2 As Range, iR As Long
    Dim Sht1 As Worksheet, Sht2 As Worksheet, ColCnt1 As Long
    Dim objDic As Object, sKey As String
    Const FIX_COLS = 2
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Load table1
    Set Sht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    arrData1 = Sht1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ColCnt1 = UBound(arrData1, 2)
    ' Load table2
    Set Sht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set rngData2 = Sht2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, ColCnt1)
    arrData2 = rngData2.Value
    ' Load into Dict object
    For i = LBound(arrData1) + 1 To UBound(arrData1)
        sKey = arrData1(i, 1) & "|" & arrData1(i, 2)
        objDic(sKey) = i
    Next i
    ' Loop through table2
    For i = LBound(arrData2) + 1 To UBound(arrData2)
        sKey = arrData2(i, 1) & "|" & arrData2(i, 2)
        If objDic.Exists(sKey) Then
            iR = objDic(sKey)
            ' Populate data (copy row)
            For j = FIX_COLS + 1 To ColCnt1
                arrData2(i, j) = arrData1(iR, j)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    ' Write output to table2
    rngData2.Value = arrData2
    ' Copy over table1 header
    Sht1.Rows(1).Copy Sht2.Range("A1")
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thats good. Tell me please, if I make it as function, like: `Function Demo(rng As Range,  colKey As String, Optional colKey1 As String = 0, ... Optional colKeyX As String = 0)` is there any other way then `select case NumberOfColKeys` or for loop to set `sKey = arrData1(i, colKey) & "|" & arrData1(i, colKey1)`?